# Как добавить колонку с индексом промежутков времени?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Хочу сделать колонку `df['Period']`, в которой значения `Time` будут обозначены значением `Period`, каждый промежуток по 15 минут. То есть, каждый период обозначается как 1,2,3.....1241 и тп.

По сути, это `pandas.DatetimeIndex`, но в этой задаче как применить это не знаю, возможно его не следует применять.

```
    Date        Time    Score
0   20200601    100000  35.32
1   20200601    100000  35.32
2   20200601    100001  35.32
3   20200601    100001  35.32
4   20200601    100001  35.32
5   20200601    100001  35.31
6   20200601    100001  35.32
7   20200601    100002  35.32
...
83  20200601    101602  35.32
84  20200601    101603  35.32
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
    Date        Time    Score  Period
0   20200601    100000  35.32  1
1   20200601    100000  35.32  1
2   20200601    100001  35.32  1
3   20200601    100001  35.32  1
4   20200601    100001  35.32  1
5   20200601    100001  35.31  1
6   20200601    100001  35.32  1
7   20200601    100002  35.32  1
...
83  20200601    101602  35.32  2
84  20200601    101603  35.32  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["Period"] = (df
                .assign(dt=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype(str) + df["Time"].astype(str), 
                                          format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
                .groupby(pd.Grouper(key="dt", freq="15T")).ngroup() + 1
```

результат:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
          Date    Time  Score  Period
0     20200601  100000  35.32       1
1     20200601  100000  35.32       1
2     20200601  100001  35.32       1
3     20200601  100001  35.32       1
4     20200601  100001  35.32       1
...        ...     ...    ...     ...
1398  20200601  114407  35.31       7
1399  20200601  114407  35.31       7
1400  20200601  114407  35.31       7
1401  20200601  114407  35.31       7
1402  20200601  114407  35.31       7

[1403 rows x 4 columns]
```